# Please vote for synonym suggestions

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

As I post this, we have ten outstanding suggestions for tag synonyms, some of them for more than four years. I therefore think it is more than time to urge a decision on these.
This is the first part of a small initiative to reach such a decision.

**If you have more than [2500 reputation](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)**, please

- Open [the list of active synonym suggestions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest).
- Click on the master tag for all the synonym suggestions with which you agree or disagree.
- Cast the respective vote on the respective synonym suggestion.

(In a second step, I will subject the remaining synonyms to general voting.)

If you feel that any suggestion requires a more extensive suggestion, please [ask a separate meta question](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Ow, that voting interface is outright bad. What was wrong with a vote button on the linked page already? These features are already almost invisible to start with...

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Yes, it’s universally agreed upon that the tag synonymisation system is pretty bad. Still, as it stands, we got to make the best of it.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Can a user who has less than 2500 reputation suggest tag synonyms by opening a question on meta? Or is this discouraged?

Comment: @GoodDeeds: Sure, you can suggest a synonym.